# another instance of an application is already in process - visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, authentication, tfs

I am attempting to log into Microsoft Visual Studio, so I can connect to TFS, and I am unable to login.

After I enter my credentials, it acts like everything is good to go but I do not login in the top right. When I hover over Sign in I get an error stating "Another instance of the application is already in the process of signing in."

I did just remove my user settings because of another issue not allowing me to actually connect to anything because I just branched a product.

I have attempted to shutdown the computer, restart visual Studio, reinstall visual studio and I also reinstalled microsoft office; as well as. added the two sites mentioned from another forum to my trusted sites (*.accesscontrol.windows.net)(https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/me?mkt=en-US). if anyone has any information on this that would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Sounds like you have some issues.  Have you checked and verified that it is not running in Task Manager?  I have never used the Login feature, personally, but had to for other work environments to keep MSDN license truency correct.  Sounds like you have a typical MS reboot/restart process, so check your MSCONFIG for potentialy services restart.

Comment: yeah I checked to make sure multiple instance weren't running. It was so strange. We branched a product and then I had a dll error so I restarted VS and it would crash upon opening. I believe that had something to do with my VS thinking there were 3 different projects when really there were only 1. We reset user settings and that is when it started. I am assuming it was licensing issue tied to my userID registry.

Answer (score 1):

Just try below things to narrow down the VS sign in issue:

- Disable any Anti-Virus or Anti-Spyware software on your
  computer, navigate to  `<Visual Studio Installation Path>\Common7\IDE`
  and run the following commands: `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`, it will
  take a couple of minutes to run as Visual Studio cleans up and sets
  itself back to its original state.
- Close visual studio --> delete the following registry key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSCommon\ConnectedUser\IdeUserV2`
  --> restart visual studio --> Try and sign in
- Remove credenticals from **Credential Manager** (`Control Panel\All
  Control Panel Items\Credential Manager`)

  Clean VS caches:

  1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task
     Manager)
  2. Delete the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache` directory
  3. Restart Visual Studio.
- Open the following file in notepad:
  `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

  Add 
  `65.52.55.39` and `app.vsspsext.visualstudio.com` then re-open vs and try the sign in again.

However it's not necessary to sing in Visual Studio if you just want to connect to TFS. You can only manage the connections in **Team Explorer**. When you add a new TFS server and try to connect, it will prompt to enter the credetical. Just enter the appropriate TFS credentical to connect the TFS server.

[image]

Comment: Deleting the user registry worked for me. Thanks! I am unable to upvote since this is a new account. as soon as I can I will Andy! thank you so much

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this; I believe it was the `devenv /resetuserdata` that fixed my situation, which was the sign-in issue noted here (although on VS 2015), as well as an error in Team Explorer on the Manage Connections page after connecting to a TFS team project. Running this command (which actually deleted the entire `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>` folder automatically, so I had no need to manually clear the component cache afterwards) resolved both of these issues for me.